# ¿Cómo calcular el tamaño de un CLOB?

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

Estoy trabajando con una base de datos Oracle, y uno de los campos es de tipo `CLOB` (que puede almacenar hasta  2.147,483.647 caracteres). Ese campo en particular guarda el contenido de un documento, y me gustaría saber cuál es su tamaño (el número de caracteres que contiene).

He intentado usando `LENGTH`, algo como esto:

```
SELECT LENGTH(campo_clob) FROM miTabla WHERE id = miId
```

Pero aunque funciona perfectamente con un `VARCHAR2`, parece no funcionar con el `CLOB` y siempre recibo una respuesta vacía (OJO: no cero, sino una respuesta vacío), a pesar de que el campo tiene valores (porque lo leo desde el servidor y lo escribo por pantalla).

Entonces, ¿existe alguna manera de saber el tamaño del texto que contiene el `CLOB` con SQL? (sin necesidad de tener que exportar todo el contenido al servidor y calcular el tamaño desde ahí)

Comment: Tal ves te sirva este link http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_find_length_clob.htm

Comment: Cuando te refieres a tamaño, quieres saber la cantidad de caracteres o el tamaño en bytes?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho Me refiero a número de caracteres. Edito la pregunta para indicarlo mejor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Según la [documentación](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm) de Oracle:

> The **LENGTH** functions return the length of *char*.
>   *char* can be any of the datatypes CHAR, VARCHAR2, NCHAR, NVARCHAR2, **CLOB**, or NCLOB. The return value is of datatype NUMBER. If char has
>   datatype CHAR, then the length includes all trailing blanks. If char
>   is null, then this function returns null.

Es decir, `LENGTH` debiera ser totalmente funcional en tu caso, para campos `CLOB`, por lo tanto entiendo que el problema debiera estar en otro lugar, la únicas situación que se me ocurre es que la columna sea `NULL`, en este caso `LENGTH` devuelve NULL, pero ya has verificado que no.

Con el siguiente ejemplo:

```
CREATE TABLE Ejemplo (
    Dato CLOB,
    OtroDato BLOB
)\\

INSERT INTO Ejemplo (Dato) VALUES(UNISTR('abc\00e5\00f1\00f6'))\\
INSERT INTO Ejemplo (Dato) VALUES('')\\

update Ejemplo set OtroDato = Dato\\

SELECT LENGTH(Dato),
       Dato
  FROM Ejemplo\\
```

Obtenemos la siguiente salida:

```
LENGTH(DATO)    DATO
=============== ======
6               abcåñö
NULL            NULL
```

Vemos que `LENGTH` midió correctamente la longitud del `CLOB` en caracteres y no bytes (uno de los datos insertados es multibyte), también he hecho pruebas aumentando el tamaño del dato `CLOB` lo suficiente como para descartar que sea un problema de tamaño. Con el dato `NULL`, sin embargo vemos que la longitud retornada es `NULL`, es lo más parecido a la situación que has descripto, aunque en tu caso por lo que comentas efectivamente la columna tiene datos.

Con respecto al uso de `DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH()` mencionado en la respuesta anterior, no creo que haga ninguna diferencia a `LENGTH`, al menos con los campos `CLOB`, en ambos casos debieran retornar la longitud en caracteres. Si puede haber una diferencia en los campos `BLOB`, dónde `LENGHT` al menos mirando la documentación no sabremos como va a comportarse (no se incluye el `BLOB` como un tipo válido para la función) y `DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH()` retornará efectivamente la longitud pero en bytes.

Answer (score 1):

La función [`GETLENGTH`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS66709) del paquete [`DBMS_LOB`](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/ARPLS/d_lob.htm#ARPLS600) regresa la longitud de un `LOB`, ya sea en bytes (`BLOB` o `BFILE`) o en caracteres (`CLOB`) o `NULL` si el `LOB` de entrada es `NULL` o inválido. Ejemplo:

```
  SELECT DBMS_LOB.GETLENGTH(campo_clob)
    FROM miTabla
   WHERE id = miId
```